# What is the problem with compiling this tex file?

Tags: moderncv, xepersian

This is a `moderncv` in Persian. I used to compile it smoothly but now I cannot. The error it says is as follows:

> untitled-3.tex 15 Undefined control sequence. l.15 \cvtheme
>                [blue]{bidiclassic}

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{bidimoderncv}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}%
%\setlength{\bibhang}{2em}
\cvtheme[blue]{bidiclassic}%casual} 
\usepackage{pifont}
%\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont[Scale=1]{B Zar}%{XB Niloofar}%{B Nazanin}%
\setdigitfont{B Zar}%{XB Niloofar}%{B Nazanin}%
\setlatintextfont[Scale=1]{Linux Libertine}%{Times New Roman}%
%\defpersianfont\nastaliq[Scale=1.2]{IranNastaliq}
\defpersianfont\mytitlefont[Scale=.8]{XB Kayhan Sayeh}
\AtBeginDocument{\recomputelengths} 
\firstname{\mytitlefont رضا}
\familyname{\mytitlefont فرزانه\newline\hspace*{10mm}}%\newline\hspace*{10mm}
\resumename{رزومه}
\title {\upshape \fontsize{0.5cm}{1em}\selectfont{} \hspace*{2mm}شرح حال }
\address
{\upshape  گروه فلسفه\\ دانشکده ادبیات\\ دانشگاه کرمان\\ تهران، ایران}
\mobile{091939870283} 
%\fax{شماره فکس}   
\extrainfo{\emailsymbol \emaillink{ Farzaanegan.r.77@gmail.com}}
%\quote{نقل قول}  


\begin{document}
1
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure, if `Scale` is correct. on another note: are you sure, you want to leave your personal information out in the open on the internet like that?

Comment: @naphaneal The personal information is not real!

Comment: please don't just say it doesn't compile, show the exact error from the log in a code section so line ends preserved.  I (and others) don't have the fonts so can't run the example, but could still possibly debug, given an error message.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The question is now edited.

Comment: @naphaneal The question is now edited.

Comment: Your example compiles for me once I matched it up to the fonts on my system. I had to download a font (XB Zar), and change the font commands to use that (and change `Linux Libertine` to `Linux Libertine O`).

Comment: The `\cvtheme` command actually constructs a `\RequirePackage` command from its arguments. In your case it makes `\RequirePackage[blue]{cvthemebidiclassic}`, so there must be a file `cvthemebidiclassic.sty` installed on your system.

Comment: It's a sign of trouble that the class calls `\cvtheme{bidi-casual}` by default: this results in the command `\RequirePackage{cvthemebidi-casual}` but in TeXLive 2017 the installed package is `cvthemebidicasual.sty`, without the hyphen. There are many other examples of bad programming practice in this class.

Comment: But the `bidimoderncv` class does define the command `\cvtheme`, so if you're getting the error `Undefined control sequence` with this, there's some other problem.

Comment: @musarithmia So it works with downloading XB zar and adding zero?

Comment: @musarithmia Did you compile it with xelatex??

Comment: You do have to compile with `xelatex`, and you have to have the fonts that you specify installed on your system. I didn't have the fonts you named, so I used ones available to me, `XB Zar` and `Linux Libertine O` (that's an O as in OpenType, not zero).

Answer (score 2):

You need to check the availability of the selected fonts of the source file in the font directory of your operating system. In this case, `Linux Libertine` and `XB Kayhan Sayeh` must do exist in your system. In my case, I can simply substitute them with some other options like `Times New Roman` and `XB Niloofar`. Saying

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{bidimoderncv}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\usepackage{pifont}

\cvtheme[blue]{bidiclassic}

\settextfont[Scale=1]{B Zar}
\setdigitfont{B Zar}
\setlatintextfont[Scale=1]{Times New Roman}
\defpersianfont\mytitlefont[Scale=.8]{XB Niloofar}
\AtBeginDocument{\recomputelengths} 

\firstname{\mytitlefont رضا}
\familyname{\mytitlefont فرزانه\newline\hspace*{10mm}}
\resumename{رزومه}
\title {\upshape \fontsize{0.5cm}{1em}\selectfont{} \hspace*{2mm}شرح حال }
\address
{\upshape  گروه فلسفه\\ دانشکده ادبیات\\ دانشگاه کرمان\\ تهران، ایران}
\mobile{091939870283} 
\extrainfo{\emailsymbol \emaillink{ Farzaanegan.r.77@gmail.com}}

\begin{document}
این رزومه متعلق به رضا فرزانه است.
\end{document}
```

applying `XeLaTeX` to the file yields a perfect compilation:

[image]

Comment: This doesn’t explain the error message in the OP. If the problem was just missing fonts, there wouldn’t be that error.